# Membership.GetUser(username) - how to return correct casing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I am getting the username from the URL so blah.com/kevinuk.

I want some content on the page to say KevinUK which is whats stored in the membership table but when I do the following, it returns the same casing as what the input was.

```
MembershipUser member = Membership.GetUser(user);
string userName = member.UserName;
```

How do I use a lowercase username as the parameter and return the value from the database with the correct casing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which Membership provider that you are using, but you can easily descend from that and override the GetUser method.

Create a class that class inherited from MembershipProvider class.

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider

{

    public MyMembershipProvider()

    {

        //

        // TODO: Add constructor logic here

        //

    }

}
```

Override the getUser Method.

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)

{
 ... Logic here to do a case insensitive lookup...

}
```

Finally update the web config to use your new provider:

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="10">
        <providers>
            <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="Providers.FIFAMembershipProvider"     connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" ... />
        </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

Some examples:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/30c3a27d-89ff-4f87-9762-37431805ef81/aspnet-custom-membership.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `Membership.GetUser(string username)` method simply sets the `MembershipUser`'s username to the value of the passed parameter.  To get the correct casing, you'll either need to use `Membership.GetUser(object providerUserKey)`, which takes the user's GUID, or override the former method and its respective stored procedure to return the properly-cased username.

Or, you could simply make back-to-back calls to the two different `GetUser()` methods, but that's quite wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Stumpled on the same issue and tried above solution = Easiest way of getting correct casing:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userName.Text);
user = Membership.GetUser(user.ProviderUserKey);
var correctCasing = user.UserName;
```